# Binary serialization for compact framework 3.5

Tags: .net, serialization, compact-framework

I just realized that CF3.5 doesn't support the binary formatter. I'm using it to send objects over the network and now need to use something else to serialize my data... 
I heard about Google protocol buffers but found a version that has a bug under CF...

What serialization framework is good for CF?

Update:
I forgot to mention, I need it for a commercial product... so GPL won't help

Comment: Must. Increase. Accept. Rate.

Comment: Just to re-iterate Mau's statements, please accept an answer - it helps improve the response you are likely to get in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two that I know of:

[protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

[OpenNxSerialization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/OpenNxSerialization.aspx?msg=2505821)

I've had experience with both (though not on CF) and they are both very quick and easy to use.  They both specify support for CF I believe.

Answer (score 1):

We use:
[CompactFormatterPlus](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CF_serializer.aspx?msg=3046471) + [DotNetRemoting](http://dotnetremoting.com/serializationstudio.aspx) (Corrected)

I belive this also has a binary serializer in it:
[OpenNETCFIOSerial](http://www.opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/OpenNETCFIOSerial/tabid/252/Default.aspx)

Correction we actually use the CompactFormatterPlus.  I do think that OpenNetCF also has a binary serializer as well.  Our data that we sync can be up to 20 Meg in size per device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [db4o](http://www.db4o.com) and configure it to use a [MemoryBin](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/java/api/com/db4o/io/MemoryBin.html) as the backing storage and then send the bytes over the wire.

PS: the link points to Java documentation because [db4o .Net documentation](http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.12/net35/api/db4o.chm) is in CHM format.