# Communication between Desktop Application and Windows Mobile Compact Framework c#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, desktop

I am writing a desktop application that will have to communicate with a windows mobile application in the compact framework 3.5. The communication must occur over the internet between these two applications to send data between them on command if the connection is available.

The system will send messages and objects like Images between device and desktop application and check to see if the desktop can see the device by sending a command and have a timeout on response. (Application will then know that the device is not available).
The mobile device will send a message to the desktop application when online as well that the desktop knows that the mobile is connected(Type of registering for communication)

Can someone please inform me of the best way to follow to accomplish this.

I did some research and found this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164240.aspx) is near to something like event based driven communication I would want but do not have the availability of setting up an email on each device.

Battery life and internet open on device is not an issue.

Should I check in on working with the System.Net.Socket class for this type of communication between the two application and if so how will I set up so firewalls will not interfere and have my desktop application be seen over the internet by the mobile application ?

Hope someone can spread some light over this for me, if you have a answer please provide a link so I can read up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your description is something basic. OK, regardless of what TCP/IP communication you decide for (HTTP, sockets) you must always have your internet router forward packages on a specified incoming port to your PC and the firwall must accept these incoming requests.

So, the device will have to send data to the PC and vice versa. So you need a server and a client on the PC and on the PC.

Possibly you can use an already available cloud like Dropbox to exchange files between PC and device.

What are about your skills in socket programming? The main server (PC) must be written multithread to be able to server multiple device client requests.

A simple socket comm is done in my SocketWedge [http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2010/05/27/transmit-data-from-winmo-device-to-pc-socketwedge-and-socketsend/]. A way of multithreaded communication using a web server on the device is available here [http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/10/19/windows-mobile-a-simple-web-server-with-extended-features/].

Will SQL with data synchronization be a possible choice?

Can you describe the application in more detail?

~josef

Comment: Hi, I am doing some tests on programming between mobile and desktop. After a lot of research I went with the tcp port forwarding and got everything working. Do have comms as multi threaded as well and would say my skill is about 7 out of 10 maybe more but do not like saying that as can always learn from other. At the moment struggling to serialize a class object to send between pc and device if the class contains an Image object. I use http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ for serializing on both server and mobile but stuck on image.

Comment: Do you maybe have some Information on serializing objects in compact framework? Still researching and if I can even only be able to serialize the image as an object and convert it back to an image in code will also work. Can test if the object is an image by having a enum in the class specifying it.

Comment: Was thinking of converting the image to a base 64 as done that before but would like to know if there may be any better options out there

Comment: I think this is outside this question. Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236960/binary-serialization-for-compact-framework-3-5?rq=1